# How can I work around Access-Control-Allow-Origin in extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My requests fail because of the same origin policy, but is there anyway I can work around this in extensions using the webRequest api to modify the headers?

Comment: For development purposes you can also use the `--disable-web-security` Chrome flag. If the request is generated by your extension, you need to add the URL to the `permissions` section of your manifest file.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean all websites can do cross-origin requests? Not cool

Comment: About the flag: Yes, that's why I said "development purposes". About the "permissions" key: No, only your extension will be able to make the cross-origin requests. Your current solution allows anyone to make cross-origin requests to the list of URLs.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your background.js file:

```
/**
 * Force Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 *
 * Ideally, we'll want to remove this for production,
 * and actually set the header server side instead.
 */
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function onHeadersReceived(resp) {
  var len = resp.responseHeaders.length;
  while(--len) {
    if(resp.responseHeaders[len].name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-origin") {
      resp.responseHeaders[len].value = "*";
      break;
    }
  }
  if (len === 0) { //if we didn't find it len will be zero
    resp.responseHeaders.push({
      'name': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'value': '*'
    });
  }
  return {responseHeaders: resp.responseHeaders};
}, {
  urls: ['*://*.YOU-API-DOMAIN.com/*', '*://localhost/*'],
  /*TYPES: "main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script",
           "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other" */
  types: ['xmlhttprequest']
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

And also add these to your manifest.json permissions:

```
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking"
```

Reload extension and you should be good to go!

Comment: Devin, `header` is undefined in code. it should be resp.responseHeaders[len].name instead header.